# Taking sql DB backup through Custom artisan cammand laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am taking a `MySQL` DB backup with custom generated `artisan command`, the command runs successfully and also created a `backup` file without any error `exception` but the file is empty.

```
class BackupDatabase extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'db:backup';
    protected $description = 'Backup the database';
    protected $process;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $today = \today()->format('Y-m-d');
        if (!\is_dir(\storage_path('backups'))) {
            \mkdir(\storage_path('backups'));
        }

        $this->process = new Process(sprintf(
            'mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s > %s',
            config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
            storage_path("backups/{$today}.sql")
        ));
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->process->run();

            $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            $this->error('The backup process has been failed.', $exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you copy the string generated in the command and run it manually, is the file exported still empty?

Comment: yes, when trying manually also getting empty file

Comment: Then it is not the Laravel command causing the issue. Your MySQL command is the issue. Log into the database via command line using the credentials that you're using and then select the database that you're using. If you see data then it might just be permissions.

Comment: Could you please provide the generated command string.

Comment: am using this  ```php artisan db:backup``` and m using XAMPP mysql

Comment: @itxrahulsingh I meant the `mysqldump` command generated.

Comment: @bogdan actually I'm noob and I don't know how to get this

Comment: Dump the `sprintf` results by adding a line like this `dd(sprintf('mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s > %s', ...))` in your backup command and running `php artisan db:backup`. That will dump the generated command to your console.

Comment: here is generated command ```mysqldump -uroot -p laravelApp > /Users/rahul/laravelApp/storage/backups/2019-11-12.sql```

Comment: @itxrahulsingh try this `mysqldump --compact -u%s -p%s %s > %s` this will work hopefully